# Change the date format in R

Tags: r

Is there a way to change the date format in R. Example, when I tried with below formula to convert, it was not showing a right result

```
format(as.Date("30-01-2021"), "%Y/%d/%m")
"0030/20/01"
```

Expected output

```
"2021-01-30"
```

Comment: Try `as.Date("30-01-2021", format="%d-%m-%Y")`, you need to define the input format correctly.

Comment: Thanks. But its strange that ````format(as.Date("2020-02-01"), "%W")```` is showing as Week 4.  It should be week 1 right?

Comment: Read `?strptime` should all be well documented there.

Comment: If month is 02 how can week be 1?

Answer (score 2):

The `lubridate` package works really well for this kind of formatting.

```
#Load library
library('lubridate')

# Convert date format
lubridate::dmy("30-01-2021")
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason it is not working is because your date string is not in the default date format.  The default is "%Y-%m-%d" but your string is "%d-%m-%Y".  So you can fix it by specifying the input date format on the `as.Date()` function.  Like this:

```
as.Date("30-01-2021", "%d-%m-%Y")
# [1] "2021-01-30"
```